# Correct way to update a state inside useReducer (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, use-state, use-reducer

I have two 'select' inputs (html) that work togueter to display info, this is the state:

```
const [foodValues, setFoodValues] = useState({ type: 'Everything', category: 'Everything' })
```

Everything works just fine, I'm using a classic handleChange() on both inputs:

```
const handleChange = e => {
    const value = e.target.value 
    const name = e.target.name
    dispatch({type: ACTIONS.CHANGE, payload: {e: value, name: name}})
}
```

As you can see, I call the dispatch to use the useReducer:

```
const OperationsReducer = (foodReducer, action) => {
  const { foodValues, setFoodValues } = useContext(AllContext)

  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.CHANGE:
      setFoodValues({
        ...foodValues,
        [action.payload.name]: action.payload.e
     })
   break;
  }
}
```

And it works just fine! But I'm getting this warning in the console:

> warning Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks. You can only call Hooks at the top level of your React function. For more information, see

So, my question is: is there a way to use this useReducer without that warning? **I know I could just use setFoodValues outside of it, but I'm curious (I really like using useReducer...).** I already read the React docs on this topic, but I saw some people doing some really weird (and cool) to stuff to work around this.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: if you you create your own hook it has to be called "use....", in your example `useOperationsReducer`, but i think there is something complete wrong in your logic, and how you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const initialState = { type: 'Everything', category: 'Everything' };

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.CHANGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.name]: action.payload.e
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function Component() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const handleChange = e => {
    const value = e.target.value
    const name = e.target.name
    dispatch({type: ACTIONS.CHANGE, payload: {e: value, name: name}})
  }
  
  ...
}
```